# Passing value from a hyperlink to new page

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone take a look at my code? I am trying to display a record from a link from the previous page. When I echo $id (below)... it displays the value of 'id' from the previous page. However the query returns all rows of the table. I had it working earlier. I have since changed something. Pleas point out what I over looking. Thank you, in advance.

```
<?php
mysql_connect('host', 'userid', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('my_database') or die (mysql_error());
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from table");

$id= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);


echo $id;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uatbeta1 WHERE id=".intval($_REQUEST['id']));

if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}


$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $result;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//Display the results from the current row and a line break

echo "<table border='1'>";




echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['company']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['constructioncontractor']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['weldingcontractor']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['ndtcontractor']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['weldid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['projectname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['examinationdate']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['shift']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Please do not use the mysql_ functions as they are being deprecated http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Comment: Klevis,Can you recommend a substitute for mysql_query?

Comment: Use pdo http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$id`? You have it nicely escaped, so use that variable:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uatbeta1 WHERE id=".$id);
```

Comment: I second what Veger said (whom beat me to it). Although $_REQUEST should work and be able to get data from $_GET and $_POST, I would just use $id in the query. Also, if this is an page in the internet, I would check out MySQLi or PDO for added security instead of using MySQL_query.